# Laravel how to pass null value in route parameter in front end

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a form and I'm trying to pass null value into the `$dev-id` parameter but it doesnt work, instead ti will replace the dev id parameter with the `$id` as shown in my code at the bottom,

The reason i needed it to be null because I'm using this function for 2 different page but one of the page doesn't have `$dev_id`. any help is appreciated

HTML:

```
<form method="post"
    action="{{ route('admin.developers.admins.edit.post',['admin' => $admin, 'dev_id' => null, 'id' => $id]) }}" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
```

web.php :

```
Route::post('developers/{dev_id?}/admins/{id}/edit', 'Admin\DeveloperAdminController@postEditDeveloperAdmin')->name('admin.developers.admins.edit.post')->where(['dev_id' => '[0-9]+', 'id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

Comment: Could you add the following to your question: _1. the route definition from your routes file_ _2. the url that it currently generates_  _3.  the url you are expecting it to generate_. Your question does not make much sense to me currently, why would you want to set a route parameter to null.

Comment: ok noted, the result is im sharing the post function in 2 different page, but the other page doesn't have and $dev_id

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those parametres in the form of hidden input and in controller use request to get those values
Add these to yur form

```
 <input type="hidden" value="anything" name="dev_id"> 
Instead you are using vue use `v-model` instead of name and value
```

Now modify your form like this

```
<form method="post"
    action="{{ route('admin.developers.admins.edit.post',['admin' => $admin,'id' => $id]) }}" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
```

Now you are access that using `$request` object in your logic and check if the value is null or not